# How can I optimize this program?

Tags: c++, optimization

I'm trying to optimize a c++ code,it reads an integer M(M<2^31) and calculates M*M*25.Since M*M*25 overflows,I wrote the program in a different way.
It has finished a testcase with 15 million integers in 0.2 seconds,which is pretty impressing,but it's still too slow for my project.If anyone can optimize the code or rewrite it using asm to make it faster,please post your code.
Here is my code:

```
#pragma GCC target("sse,sse2,sse3,ssse3,sse4,popcnt,abm,mmx,avx,tune=native")
#pragma GCC optimize("Ofast,unroll-loops,no-stack-protector,fast-math")
#pragma comment(linker, "/stack:200000000")

#include <cstdint>
#include <stdio.h>

char buf[1 << 20];
char* p1 = buf;
char* p2 = buf;

inline int getc() {
    return (p1 == p2) && (p2 = (p1 = buf) + fread_unlocked(buf, 1, 1 << 20, stdin), p1 == p2) ? EOF : *p1++;
}

inline uint_fast64_t read() {
    uint_fast64_t ret = 0;
    uint_fast8_t ch = getc();
    while (ch >= '0' && ch <= '9') {
        ret = (ret << 1) + (ret << 3) + ch - '0';
        ch = getc();
    }
    return ret;
}

inline void write(uint_fast64_t x) {
    if (x == 0) {
        putchar_unlocked(48);
        return;
    }
    uint_fast32_t stk[20];
    uint_fast32_t top = 0;
    uint_fast32_t* ptr;
    ptr = &stk[0];
    while (x) {
        *ptr = x % 10; 
        x /= 10; ptr++; 
    }
    ptr--;
    while (ptr >= (&stk[0])) { 
        putchar_unlocked(*ptr + '0'); 
        ptr--; 
    }
}
int main() 
{
    uint_fast64_t a;
    while (a = read()) {
        if (a != 1)
            write(a * a >> 2);
        if (a & 1) {
            putchar_unlocked('2');
            putchar_unlocked('5');
            putchar_unlocked('\n');
        }
        else {
            putchar_unlocked('0');
            putchar_unlocked('0');
            putchar_unlocked('\n');
        }
    }
}
```

I have optimized the I/O of the program.Since I'm not allowed to use fwrite() in this project,this is the fastest way of I/O I know.

Comment: Since you don’t have a specific issue, your question would be better suited for CodeReview.

Comment: This code is tagedd C++. There is 0 C++ in it. It is a gcc specifc C code. The code quality is bad. See ````inline int getc() {
    return (p1 == p2) && (p2 = (p1 = buf) + fread_unlocked(buf, 1, 1 << 20, stdin), p1 == p2) ? EOF : *p1++;
}```` Here you are using heavy side effects. No meaning. You are using the comma operator and other nonesense. This will not optimize your code. Go to https://godbolt.org/ and check the assembly output. In general. How you format the code is not important. The compiler will optimize that for you.

Comment: In addition to Armin's observation, I'd also suggest comments if you are asking other people to read your code.  And your code in main doesn't look right (what happens if a == 3?  It prints, then prints again. Similarly with 0 (which != 1)).  Global memory (like buf) isn't the same as stack memory (linker directive).  By asking for twice as much memory as you need, you might be increasing the load time for your program (not much, but we're only talking .2 seconds total).  Are you sure that `a * a >> 2` gives you `M*M*25`? Something doesn't seem right, but without comments, maybe I missed it?

Comment: if a==3,it outputs (3*3>>2),which is 2,then it prints '25\n',so the output will be 225\n ,which is the right answer(3*3*25=225)

Comment: p.s a is a positive integer in this project.

Answer (score 1):

Gcc provides a 128bit integer type which will be wide enough to store your result. Considering compiler optimization, this should be the fastest way to solve your problem

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <ios>

int main()
{
    /*
        By default, C++ streams are synchronized with their respective C streams.
        Turning off synchrnization may result in faster I/O operations.  For details see https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/ios_base/sync_with_stdio
    */
    std::ios::sync_with_stdio(false);
    uint64_t num;
    std::cin >> num;
    __uint128_t res = (__uint128_t)num * num * 25;

    // print res

    return 0;
}
```

Note: 128 bit integer types are only available on 64 bit targets

Comment: I don't think the line `__uint128_t res = num * num * 25;` would work correct since `num` is `uint64`.

Comment: I tried __uint128_t, but it's even slower than the original code. It took 1.8s to finish the same testcase with 15 million integers.

Comment: Besides, the code you wrote receives a Wrong Answer because you should reverse the number before you output it. Still, thanks.